# make search bar match its parent width when searching in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, searchview

first I know it's a confusing title but hear me out

I'm creating a song app where you have multiple songs and when you press on a song the app shows you the songs lyrics.
I searched on google how to make a search bar and I got it working. What I don't like about it is that it doesn't fully go to the left.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4KPs.jpg) is what I'm talking about

I want the text to disappear and the search bar to take what space is left

My MainActivity file

```kotlin
package com.biskyy.caietdecantarikt



import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.SearchView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<*>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))


        adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resources.getStringArray(R.array.cntArrays))
        lv_listView.adapter = adapter
        lv_listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{ parent, view, position, id ->

            when (position) {
                0 -> {
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cantare)
                }

            }

            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        lv_listView.emptyView = tv_emptyTextView

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)

        val search = menu?.findItem(R.id.ic_search)
        val searchView = search?.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.queryHint = "Cautati o cantare"

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                adapter.filter.filter(newText)

                return true
            }
        })
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

}
```

My activity_main.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CaietDeCantariKT.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.CaietDeCantariKT.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_emptyTextView"
        android:text="Niciun rezultat"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my menu_main.xml file

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.biskyy.caietdecantarikt.MainActivity" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate()` somewhere after calling `setSupportActionBar(...)`, try adding:

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`

This should hide the title and your searchbar should expand to take the entire width.